# Special Character check using Java Pattern

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I want to generate Two patterns with below information,

1)The following special characters cannot be entered in the first name, last name, email, phone number fields in the Account form:

**Pattern**  " [ ] : ; | = + * ? < > / \ ,
**Names cannot start with a period**

2)The following special characters cannot be entered in the Company address fields:

**Pattern** < > / \ |

Please give me an idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: For the first pattern [<>[]:;/\"|=+*?,] For the Second Pattern [<>/\"|] Is this correct? I dont know how can we check for Names cannot start with a period, Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try these patterns**

*for 1st point*

```
(?i)^([a-z][^"\[:\]\|=\+\*\?<>\\\/\r\n]+)$
```

*for 2st point*

```
(?i)^([a-z][^<>\\\/\|\r\n]+)$
```

**Explanations**

```
1st Pattern

"(?i)" +                               -- Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i)
"^" +                                  -- Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
"(" +                                  -- Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   "[a-z]" +                              -- Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
   "[^\"\\[:\\]\\|=\\+\\*\\?<>\\\\\\/\r\n]" +       -- Match a single character NOT present in the list below
                                             -- The character “"”
                                             -- A [ character
                                             -- The character “:”
                                             -- A ] character
                                             -- A | character
                                             -- The character “=”
                                             -- A + character
                                             -- A * character
                                             -- A ? character
                                             -- One of the characters “<>”
                                             -- A \ character
                                             -- A / character
                                             -- A carriage return character
                                             -- A line feed character
      "+" +                                  -- Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
")" +
"$"                                    -- Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)


2nd Pattern

"(?i)" +                  -- Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i)
"^" +                     -- Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
"(" +                     -- Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   "[a-z]" +                 -- Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
   "[^<>\\\\\\/\\|\r\n]" +       -- Match a single character NOT present in the list below
                                -- One of the characters “<>”
                                -- A \ character
                                -- A / character
                                -- A | character
                                -- A carriage return character
                                -- A line feed character
      "+" +                     -- Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
")" +
"$"                       -- Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)
```

**code**

```
try {
    boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("(?i)^([a-z][^\"\\[:\\]|=+*?<>\\\\/\\r\\n]+)$");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: Excellent Cylian,Thanks a lot for the detail explanation, I just wanted to confirm that for 1st point, Is this also checking Names cannot start with a period??

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that for 1st point, Is this also checking Names cannot start with a period?? and For 2nd point its giving compilation error like Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ) Can you please verify same?

Comment: @MayurPatel I can tell you that the first regex does *not* care whether the string starts with a period

Comment: @MayurPatel: The RegEx I provided here, is basic and need to escaped as needed by compiler.

Comment: @Andy: The pattern doesn't match any string that starts-with a ``dot``.

Comment: @MayurPatel I think it will be "\n" causing the compilation error because it can be used a standard string. If I remember rightly you need to put "\\n"

Comment: @Andy Same thing is there in 1st point n that's not giving any error but in 2nd point its giving, Thanks I will check that.

Comment: @Andy: You're right, it was just an typo. Thanks for spotting that. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regular expression, which you're obviously not confident with, you could use the `String.contains()` method.

However, if you must use regex, like Mayur Patel said, "`[ab]`" basically means a or b ! You should check out regularexpressions.info

Comment: String.contains which is the standard way to check for Special character,Regex Pattern is the option which we can for it But I dont have much idea how to create pattern which I specified

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution of my problem

1) (?i)^([a-z][^\"\[:\]|=+*.?<>\\/\r\n]+)$

2) (?i)^([a-z][^\"<>|\\/\r\n]+)$

I've also added period symbol in 1) point for checking not to start Names with period symbol.

Thanks a lot Cylian and Andy for the help, It really helped me a lot.

Thanks again :)